# Can't run time delay text on Mac terminal (Python)

Tags: python, text, delay, typewriter

I'm having trouble with the Terminal on my Mac. 
I'm trying to print out delay text (like it appears on a type writer) and the code (below) was correct when I tested on an online compiler.

```
import sys
import time


intro1= "Welcome player. What's your name?"

for x in intro1:
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

But my Mac Terminal just freezes for a sec and print out the whole statement in one go. I got Python 2.7.10 on the Mac. I looked up online and I think my Terminal is cutting the buffer for convenience's sake but now I actually *need* the buffer (I'm going to be printing out delayed text *a lot*). Is there any statement to turn on the buffer (or fix it since it should be set by default) on my Terminal? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `sys.stdout.write()` to force the character out instead of letting it get buffered:

```
import sys
import time

introduction = "Welcome player.  What's your name? "

for character in introduction:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)

name = raw_input()
```

Comment: Do I have to do this *every time* I want to print something? Is there one statement to put in before the program to remind terminal that it must not buffer? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: I do not think you can turn off buffering, so the answer to your question is _yes_: you must do that every time.  However, you can define a function `write_typewriter(text,delay)` that will keep your code short.